# How would you create this geometric logo?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo

Is it as simple as creating a circle and doing step and repeat at an angle?

[image]

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is a *blend* between the outer circle and the inner ellipse.

1. Draw both ellipse and circle, both with a stroke colour and no fill.

[image]

2. Align their centers so they overlap.
3. Select the 'blend' tool.

[image]

4. Click once on the top anchor of the circle.
5. Then click the right-hand anchor of the ellipse.
6. Double-click the blend tool in the toolbox to have a dialog box pop up.
7. In the box, enter the option 'specified steps' in the drop-down, and choose a number of steps around 20, then click OK.

[image]

Comment: I prefer to use a Spirograph

Comment: Absolutely superb answer

Comment: This is the kind of thing I usually discover when NOT trying to achieve such an effect. Nice explanation of the steps.

Comment: What causes it to "flip" and cross over like it does? Is the order of selecting the anchors significant?

Comment: @NicHartley The order is irrelevant afaik, but it is important to know that the two anchors you click will the ones that flow into each other, with all other anchors following suit. The image would differ greatly if you'd click the top anchor of the circle and the bottom one of the ellipse.

Comment: Ah, okay, so the rotation is provided by telling the top anchor to go to the right. Thanks!

Comment: also worth knowing that Blend respects appearance palette work too, not just  raw vector geometry.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/92AAy.png